# Terminal on Android device itself

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm trying to follow [this advice on checking USB connectivity status](https://plus.google.com/+GeoffHoff/posts/eMsr1cyw75s) which suggests using ADB, "*or from a shell on the phone*" where I should execute:

```
cat /sys/class/typec/typec_device/current_detect
```

The latter seems great. But I can't find out **how to start a shell on my Nexus 6P with Android 6** (not rooted). Basically, I'm asking a variant of the question: "[terminal on real android device from PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/60906/16050)", but again: I'd prefer not having to use ADB.

Is this possible? Or does this require an app and/or my device to be rooted?

Comment: It requires one of many `Terminal Emulator` apps. App suggestions are *off-topic*, though.

Comment: Oh, I'm not looking for app suggestions. I know I could go to [SoftwareRecs.SE] for that, or just search the store using plain common sense. My question was whether you needed apps at all, or whether Android has this built in somewhere. If the answer is "requires an app", so be it.

Comment: The answer rather is "maybe". Stock Android IMHO doesn't ship with a terminal app, but e.g. CyanogenMod does. If you really need to go for an app, ask at SR (as you already know). I'd have some nice recommendations then :)

Comment: @Izzy Allright, [let's hear them](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37469/1008) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question seems to be: **no, there seems to be no built-in terminal**, at least not in the stock Android that comes with the Nexus 6P. You'll have to install an app for that. (I've [asked on our SoftwareRecs.SE sister site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37469/1008) which got at least one great recommendation.)